# Python Tkinter() how to remove the frame on the main window? - second question, simpler code

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have a question how to delete a frame, I want to delete this frame where there is "tk#number", "x", min? (simple example) Thank you for your help :D

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.counter = 0


def clicked():
    root.counter += 1
    label['text'] = 'Button clicked: ' + str(root.counter)


tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=clicked).pack()

label = tk.Label(root, text="No clicks yet.")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no *frame* in the window.  Do you mean the title bar of the window that has the *minimize*, *maximize* and *close* buttons? If yes, then add `root.overrideredirect(1)`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, except it doesn't work for me :/.

Comment: Thx the code works :D